# Laravel 4.2 - Use where clause on related tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am working with two models, `UserType` and `User` - `UserType` **hasMany** `User`.

I am trying to retrieve a list of Users associated with a UserType that has the property `receive_email` set to 1 (true).

I have tried:

```
$userGroups = UserType::with(['Users' => function($query) {
        $query->whereReceiveEmail(1)->whereNotNull('email')->whereNull('status');
    }])->whereIn('id', [10, 1])->get();
```

and the Where clause seems to be totally ignored. From the Laravel 4.2 docs -

```
$users = User::with(array('posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');

}))->get();
```

I have seen many people say that this is not the correct way to use eager loading constraints but I really do not know what that would be, they do not seem to do anything. So, the short question, how can I retrieve a listing of `Users` with `receive_email` set to 1 through the `UserType` relation?

---

**UPDATE**
Can someone explain to me what the example code from the docs above is supposed to do? I'm assuming that it is supposed to return Posts associated with Users that match the constraint of having a title LIKE "first." In my case, I'm trying to find Users associated with UserTypes where each User has `receive_email` set to 1. The only significant differences between my code and the example code is that I am applying `whereIn()` and the model names are different.

So, with the results from the example, would the following be true?

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
  foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
    // matching posts with titles LIKE "first"
   }
}
```

Comment: You need `whereHas`. But your question is unclear - you're talking about Users associated to UserType matching some condition, but you're querying Users instead.

Comment: If you're referring to the second code snippet, that's from the Laravel 4.2 docs (as mentioned). If you're referring to the first one, `UserType` is the model I'm querying. And could you explain the whereHas as it applies to this?

Comment: No, I'm not referring to the docs example, but yours. Lukas gave you the code already, so you know what was wrong there.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk very confused by your comments. I'm trying to find Users that are associated with a UserType that match a condition (the User must have receive_email set). Not sure how that's unclear? And how am I querying Users instead when the model I start the query with is UserType?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, also, can you explain what the query from the docs is supposed to do? My initial stab at this was based on what I saw in the 4.2 documentation, the `function($query)` bit did not seem to do anything at all, really curious about what it's supposed to do. `whereHas` is only mentioned in passing in the docs, no real details.

Comment: In your code you had constraints on the `users` query, not `usertypes`, and that's what I referred to. You must be aware that eager loading runs separate queries, thus anything in the `with` closure is applied to the other query (`users` table in this case) not the one you *started with*. The difference is this: `with` eager loads relation matching the constraints, but doesn't affect main query in any way. `whereHas` on the other hand limits the main query by the relation. That's what @lukasgeiter has shown.

Comment: Still confused - isn't that what I was doing? I am trying to get Users assigned to a UserType where each User has certain constraints. So what you're saying is that instead of querying UserTypes and then constraining the User relation I am supposed to query Users and constrain the UserType? So if I want UserType with ID 1 and 10, along with its associated Users that match a constraint... oh no, I've gone crosseyed

Comment: I think what I was trying to do is fairly clear, the documents are a bit misleading. Using the example code, let's say that instead of trying to find `Posts` belonging to `Users` that match a constraint, we're trying to find `Users` (in place of `Posts`) with constraints with an association to `UserTypes` (in place of `Users`). It's really the same thing as in the docs, just different models. Which brings me back to "what is that supposed to do?"

Comment: Well, if you want `users` then you don't query another model. That's what you have in the answer. About your **update** question - yes, that's exactly what the example would do. And no, it's not getting `posts` but `users` with posts, and that's why you would need a foreach there. Read the docs again, as well as the anwer from Lukas and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after a list of users, then I suggest you actually start with that model and make use of `whereHas` to filter by user type:

```
$users = User::where('receive_email', 1)
             ->whereNotNull('email')
             ->whereNull('status')
             ->whereHas('UserType', function($q){
                 $q->whereIn('id', [1, 10]);
             })
             ->get();
```

And actually, since the user type id should exist as foreign key in the users table, you don't even need `whereHas`:

```
$users = User::where('receive_email', 1)
             ->whereNotNull('email')
             ->whereNull('status')
             ->whereIn('user_type_id', [1, 10]);
             ->get();
```

For `RosterMember` it's basically the same. Although now you have to use `whereHas` since it's a many-to-many relation:

```
$rosterMembers = RosterMember::where('receive_email', 1)
                 ->whereNotNull('email')
                 ->whereHas('UserType', function($q){
                     $q->whereIn('user_type_id', [1, 10]);
                 })
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Never thought about approaching it from this angle. What about a Many to Many relation? `UserType` also `belongsToMany()` `RosterMember`

Comment: You mean you want to filter over two relationships?

Comment: Ideally, yes - the first (User) is a hasMany relation, the second (RosterMember) is a belongsToMany

Comment: And what would be the condition? (so I can write you an example)

Comment: Same as with User but without `whereNull('status')` - the base model in this case is `RosterMember`, but if I could get that PLUS `User`, that would be super

Comment: Wait, just to get this straight. Do you want a list of `RosterMember` filtered by `UserType` and other things, or a list of `Users` filtered by `UserType` *and* `RosterMember`?

Comment: I need a list of `User` AND `RosterMember` filtered by `UserType` where `receive_email` = 1, etc. We have a terribly messy table structure, basically a list of active ("real" users) and inactive ones - sort of an archive. They're on separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% familiar with relationships, they've always been a bit tricky. But from what I understand, you want all the `Users` in `UserType` 1 and 10 that have `receive_emails` set to 1. So, this should work:

```
$result = 
  UserType::whereIn("id", array(1, 10))
  ->first()
  ->users()
  ->where("receive_email", "=", 1)
  ->whereNotNull("emails")
  ->whereNull("status")
  ->get()
;
```

What this should do is return all the accessible fields from both id 1 and 10 of `UserType` as well as all fields from the `User` table. If you run a `dd($result)` on this query, you should see an entry for `UserType` id 1 connected to all the `Users` that have `receive_email` set to 1, and another set for `UserType` id 10.

I can't guarantee that this will work without seeing your `UserType.php` and `User.php` classes, as the relationships might not be set, but if you followed Laravel convention:

```
public function users(){
  return $this->hasMany("User");
}
```

and the inverse

```
public function userType(){
  return $this->belongsTo("UserType");
}
```

then it should work. Hope this helps! Also, I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish this, but this is what I came up with, and it seems to work on some of my existing projects with relationships.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! So what on earth are Eager Loading Constraints meant for? Because what the docs show is basically what I am trying to accomplish, or at least it appears so. And, to make this a touch more complicated, is it also possible to do this with a SECOND relation? There is also a BelongsToMany relation, `RosterMemberRecipients`: Belongs To Many `RosterMember`

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but it may be beyond my scope of knowledge. In this example, trying to call something after `->users()...->get()->roster()` (as an example) it would fail, as `->get()` returns a collection and something like `->roster()` can only be used on a single item. Edit it into the question, maybe I misunderstand the wording as well :P

Comment: It's all good, this is a good start. So what exactly are query scopes for? Wasted hours today on this. :/

Comment: To be honest, I've never used them like that example in the docs. Before I discovered this type of query I would actually keep everything separated, ie no relationships at all (which worked, but was a nightmare on updates/deletes) I would try asking someone with a gold badge for Laravel, they're the experts :)

Comment: Oh no! I may have to retract my acceptance of this answer. I just noticed that `whereIn(...)->first()` is not actually giving me all results. For example, if I use `UserType::whereIn('id', [1, 10])->first()..` I only receive results for one

Comment: Hmm... That's ok if you do. When I tested it, I got multiple results and then all the results for the `->users()` (different classes on my end, same results.) Let me look into it again.

Comment: I think the `first()` is throwing it all off, it ignores the other IDs in the array and just returns results for whatever the first UserType in the array was.

Comment: Ok, you may have to push the `users` to an array, but I'm out of time at work. I can look into it more tomorrow, sorry about that. And yes, you are correct about the `first()`, but you can't call `->users()` after `->get()`, and you can after `->first()`.

Comment: Okay, thanks Tim. I'm going to revoke my acceptance for now (nothing personal), I'll check back tomorrow. Was about to push to production when I spotted this, now gotta go back and revert everything. One of those days..

Comment: I hear ya. It happens, and no offense taken, if it's not the right answer, I agree that it shouldn't be marked as such. Hopefully we can solve this later. :)